# Two Apple Watch Companion Targets possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, watchos, watchos-10

### What I have

I have a WatchOS companion app that has a deployment target of 4.0 or later. It is written in WatchKit and UIKit (?).

### What I want to do

I want to update the WatchOS companion with the new WatchOS 10 features and write it in SwiftUI. However, I still want WatchOS 9 or earlier to have access to what I mentioned above.

Is this possible?

Comment: No.  You have to pick one.

Comment: It appears that SwiftUI is only available for watchOS 6.0+. If you want to rewrite your watch app with SwiftUI then you will need to drop support for watchOS 4 and 5.

Comment: @HangarRash, yes, that sounds doable and practical. It's just the WatchOS 10 stuff I want to offer without alienating older WatchOS people.

Comment: That's what `@available` helps with.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a practical way to approach this. Thank you!